# Conflicting versions of GCC compiler with Python 2.7.17

Tags: python, gcc

I am able to run a python script on a macOS device which has the following gcc version with Python.

[image: MAC Python]

However on a Ubuntu 18 machine, the following configuration is available

[image: Ubuntu Python]

And on a Windows 10 machine, the following is available

[image: Windows Python]

How can the Python and GCC version mentioned in the first image be setup on my Windows or Ubuntu machine since my script has compile dependencies.

Comment: The GCC mentioned is what was used to compile the Python interpreter. It has nothing to do with which GCC might be installed on your local machine and used to compile other code.

Comment: @chepner How can i change/install interpreter to gcc 9.2.0 on my ubuntu or windows machine, so that python uses it?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Python doesn't *use* `gcc`; what you are seeing is the version of `gcc` used to *compile* `python` itself, which has *no* affect at all when executing Python code.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, I am new to python. I wanted to know how i can install gcc 9.2.0 on windows or ubuntu and compile python 2.7.17 with it.

Comment: Why do you care with version of GCC is used to compile Python? For that matter, why are you compiling Python in the first place? GCC does not compile Python *scripts*, it compiles the Python *interpreter*. What does "my script has compile dependencies" mean?